# Importar un archivo JS en Angular 8.3 personalizado

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, angular8

Estoy creando una migración de un proyecto HTML hacia Angular 8 y todo funciona muy bien hasta donde tengo que agregar los archivos JS al proyecto.

Cuando los Agrego no se carga correctamente y las funcionalidades que debe hacer no se ejecutan.

Ya cargue los archivos en las siguientes raíces y no me carga el contenido del archivo js:

Desde el Angular.json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluyo los archivos JS también en el **Index** por defecto de **Angular 8** y ejecuto un mensaje **"Hola Mundo"** y el navegador lo muestra, pero la funcionalidad del archivo js como abrir el acordeon y más no funciona.

Dejo imagenes de donde tengo el archivo JS y del Componente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco cualquier aporte, sugerencia de una posible solución.

Gracias

Comment: Una cosa que no me ha quedado clara: ¿Está ese "hola mundo" en el archivo .js que intentas cargar?

Answer (score 0):

puedes agregarlos al index.html

```
<body>
//En la parte final, solo revisa en la sources que cargue los archivos
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

assets es mi carpeta donde guardo los archivos y esta src, que es donde igual se encuentra el index

Comment: Hola, como indique en la pregunta ya los anexe en el Index por defecto y no carga los componentes de mi archivo JS, no requiero instalar Bootstrap pues ya esta eso correctamente incluido, son archivos JavaScript propios con una Lógica que no se cargan en el proyecto

Comment: quita el "./" puede ser que no estés apuntando correctamente a los archivos

Comment: Los CSS me cargan bien, el problema son los archivos JS de mi propiedad que al incluirlos en el angular.json o en el index.html no carga la lógica que hay en ellos.